# ReactJS — How to use intersection observer in a Class Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intersection-observer

I manage to use `react-intersection-observer` in a Function Component. However, I have not been successful when using it with a Class Component. I tried to follow the documentation but I am getting the following error:

`Invariant failed: react-intersection-observer: No DOM node found. Make sure you forward "ref" to the root DOM element you want to observe.`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Pseudo-code

- Trigger animation when the element is visible in the viewport.

[CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hermann-sq5ox?file=/src/Timer.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-grid-system";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { InView } from "react-intersection-observer";

let years, days, hours, mins, secs;

function upTime(countTo) {
  var now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  var difference = now - countTo;

  years = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) / 365);
  days = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24));
  hours = Math.floor((difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) * 24);
  mins = Math.floor((difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) * 24 * 60);
  secs = mins * 60;

  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to = setTimeout(function() {
    upTime(countTo);
  }, 1000);
}

export default class Timer extends Component {
  state = {
    y: 0,
    d: 0,
    h: 0,
    m: 0,
    s: 0,
    toggle: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Set inital seconds
    upTime("may,05,2006,00:00:00");
    let currentSec = secs;

    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      upTime("may,05,2006,00:00:00");
      currentSec += 1;

      this.setState({
        y: years,
        d: days,
        h: hours,
        m: mins,
        s: currentSec
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.myInterval);
  }

  render() {
    const { y, h, m, s } = this.state;
    const style = {
      listStyle: "none",
      fontFamily: "Soleil",
      fontSize: "200px",
      lineHeight: "220px",
      color: "black",
      textAlign: "left"
    };

    // Animation list
    const list = {
      visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: { staggerChildren: 0.06 }
      },
      hidden: {
        opacity: 0,
        transition: {}
      }
    };

    // Animation list
    const item = {
      visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        y: 0,
        transition: { ease: "backInOut", duration: 0.8 }
      },
      hidden: { opacity: 0, y: 100 }
    };

    // Conditional render
    if (y !== 0) {
      return (
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col offset={{ xl: 1 }}>
              <InView>
                {({ inView, ref, entry }) => (
                  <motion.ul
                    ref={ref}
                    style={style}
                    initial="hidden"
                    animate={inView ? "visible" : "hidden"}
                    variants={list}
                  >
                    <motion.li variants={item}>{y}Y</motion.li>
                    <motion.li variants={item}>{h}H</motion.li>
                    <motion.li variants={item}>{m}M</motion.li>
                    <motion.li variants={item}>{s}</motion.li>
                  </motion.ul>
                )}
              </InView>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      );
    } else {
      return <div>"Loading..."</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `motion.ul` doesn't handle the function ref passed to it from the render function. Wrapping `motion.ul` with a div, and passing the ref to the div seems to work.

Comment: Thank you Ori Drori.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Motion.ul is not using the ref passed to assign to HTML element.
[Working fine with Html Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqLXS.png)